Append a json to a key which is a array in a existing json column
I have a JSON {"user": "test"} and I have an existing JSON column userjson which is {"uid": "1", "info": []} in my cassandra database.
I want to update the uid 1, and insert my JSON {"user": "test"} into the info key.
How would I do this in SQL?

We need a bit more detail to be able to respond. Please update your question with the CQL schema of the table so we can see how you modelled the data. Cheers!
